# Django: Easy way how to handle if an objects needs to be created or can be catched

Tags: django, django-forms

I have on my  website an inputfield only with an email, where customers can sign up for newsletters.

At the moment I am  handling by a function if this customer (email) exists already, if not then the object is created, if not,  then the object is catched.

There must be a simplier way  to do that in Django?  Any ideas?   Thanks  a lot

This is the simplified function:

```
def get_customer(email):
    # all only lowercase in order to avoid multiple entries
    email = email.lower()

    if Customer.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        # get customer object
        customer = Customer.objects.get(email=email)
    else:
        # save form input to database
        customer = Customer.create(email)
        customer.save()
    return customer
```

This is the real function, where I  also update optional parameters like name (which is an input in an other form):

```
def get_customer(name, email):
    # all only lowercase in order to avoid multiple entries
    email = email.lower()

    if Customer.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        # get customer object
        customer = Customer.objects.get(email=email)

        # if no name available in customer object but name given here, then update customer object
        if len(customer.name) == 0 and len(name) > 0:
            Customer.objects.filter(id=customer.id).update(name=name)
    else:
        # save form input to database
        customer = Customer.create(name, email)
        customer.save()
    return customer
```

P.S.:  I know `email = email.lower()`  is not 100% correct since   @Gmail.com  is not the same then  @gmail.com  ...

Comment: Just saw that  get_or_create  or   update_or_create  could help here ... definitely in the first  case,  but probably not in the second case?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, get_or_create helps also in the second case:

```
def get_customer(name, email):

    def customer_updated_name():
        return len(customer.name) == 0 and len(name) > 0

    email = email.lower()
    customer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
    if created or customer_updated_name:
        customer.name = name
        customer.save()
    return customer
```